# Distribution of $Y=X(1-X)$ when $X\sim U(0,L)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I was wondering if someone could provide a hint of how to solve the following problem. I am working on some of my own research and can't seem to remember how to solve a problem like this:

> Let $X\sim U(0,L)$ where $0 < L \le 1$. We wish to solve for the distribution $Y$ when
>
> \begin{equation}
> Y = X(1-X)
> \end{equation}

I would provide my work but I honestly have not made it very far. Any assistance would be great. Thank you.

Comment: is $L$ a random variable or just constant?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a change of variable. Since $X$ takes values between $0$ and $L$, the random variable $Y=X(1-X)$ takes values between $0$ and $1/4$ (if $L \geq 1/2$) or between $0$ and $L(1-L)$ (if $L \leq 1/2$).

I'll deal with the second cas. For any bounded measurable function $f$,

$$\mathbb{E} (f(Y)) = \mathbb{E} (f(X(1-X))) = \frac{1}{L} \int_0^L f(x(1-x)) \ dx.$$

Since $L \leq 1/2$, the function $x \mapsto x(1-x)$ is bijective from $[0,L]$ to $[0,1-L]$. Making the change of variables $y = x(1-x)$, you get the density of $Y$.

If $L \geq 1/2$, the function $x \mapsto x(1-x)$ is no longer bijective, and you will have to split the interval $[0,L]$ on two sub-intervals on which it will be bijective.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** The first step is to determine the support of $Y.$ Then the so-called 'PDF method' or 'transformation method' should work nicely. Maybe you can start on this, edit results into your Question, and let us know of any
*specific* difficulties you encounter.

It seems worthwhile to look at two kinds of examples:

The following brief simulation in R (for $L = 0.3 < .5)$ should help you decide on the support and give you a hint about the answer.

```
x = runif(10^6, 0, .3)
y = x*(1-x)
hist(y, prob=T, br = 50, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

And for $L = .8 > .5,$

```
x = runif(10^6, 0, .8)
y = x*(1-x)
hist(y, prob=T, br = 50, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

Plots of $y$ vs. $x$ for the two cases simulated above:

[image]